# Grafana Alerting - Send an alert notification per new condition check for Spring-Boot Prometheus metrics

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer, grafana-alerts

I am trying to create alerts using Grafana for Spring Boot metrics scraped from Prometheus. The use-case is to alert for exceptions thrown from each service. I'm using the **http_server_requests_seconds_count** metric and mentioned below is the breakdown of the PromQL query I'm using to create the graphs.

- First I'm excluding all the metrics which don't throw an exception.

  **`http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my-service-1",exception!~"None"}`**
- Next I've applied the `rate()` function since the default metric just provides a monotonous value.

  **`rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my-service-1",exception!~"None"}[5m])`**
- Then I've used the following condition to trigger an alert. (Using `max()` function as the `sum()` and the `count()` functions take the data-points into consideration, which is not my requirement)

  **`WHEN max() OF query(A,5m,now) IS ABOVE 0.02`**

  **`EVALUATE every 1m FOR 5m`**

The above setup works fine an sends a notification whenever the alert condition is met. However,I'm facing several problems with this approach.

1. I need the actual count of exceptions instead of a rate

I've tried the following approach to solve this. But, it still gives a monotonous value unless there is any new exception is thrown.

**`count_over_time(http_server_requests_seconds_count{application="my-service-1",exception!~"None"}[5m])`**

2. I'm getting several series for each exception and unless the alerting state has gone back to **Ok**, Grafana will not send a notification for a second time the condition is met from a different series.

How can I address the above issues and get Grafana to alert per new exception and also send the count instead of a rate?

Appreciate you kind help!